# How kubernetes does scheduling and deploying of pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes world and in ongoing process of understanding kubernetes in depth. 
I want to understand the exact working of pod scheduling via tiller to controller and deployment on the worker nodes. 
Please anyone provide me reference to relevant docs or links.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to understand kubernetes scheduling and helm properly?

Comment: I would like to know the exact steps from a helm install command till the pods are up and running state. i.e. the exact interaction with the kubelet and tiller

Answer (score 2):

This is one very fine blog about how kubernetes scheduler work:

https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/07/27/how-does-the-kubernetes-scheduler-work/

You should also have a look at the [performance tuning of scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/scheduler-perf-tuning/), which explains in detail idea about how can you tune your scheduler.

At last, for understanding how can you write your own scheduler, watch Kelsey Hightower's talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYcL0Un1io0)

Hope this gives you fair idea about scheduler.